# UnicodeDecodeError al convertir una fecha a cadena por los días con tilde

Tags: python, django, reportlab

Un saludo para todos.

Estoy convirtiendo una fecha obtenida con `datetime.datetime.now()` a una cadena con formato para pasarla a reportlab pero me genera un error de codificación.

```
ahora = datetime.datetime.now()
fecha_actual = ahora.strftime("%A, %d de %B %Y %I:%M %p")
fecha_informe = Paragraph(fecha_actual, styles['Normal'])
informe_ejecutivo.append(fecha_informe)
```

El resultado que se genera al formatear la cadena es la siguiente

> miércoles, 26 de junio 2019 06:53 p. m.

Y el error completo es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se aprecia el error es la codificación del carácter con tilde, como puedo solucionar este problema.

Comment: Parece que por alguna razón `strftime()` genera la cadena con codificación `latin1`, mientras que el `Paragraph()` la esperaba en `utf-8`. Prueba a hacer `fecha_actual = unicode(fecha_actual, "latin1")` a ver si de esta forma `Paragraph()` lo acepta sin problemas. Y si no `fecha_actual = unicode(fecha_actual, "latin1").encode("utf-8")`. En otro orden de cosas, veo que estás con python 2.7, que está "sentenciado" (dejará de recibir soporte en 2020). Yo iría pasando el código a python3.

Comment: También puedes revisar tu `locale` y cambiarlo (si te es posible) a `es_ES.UTF-8`, para que así salga ya directamente con el encoding correcto.

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono con `fecha_actual = unicode(fecha_actual, "latin1")` @abulafia